# Subfigure - Centering not working

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subcaption, subfig, sidewaysfigure

I'd like to include two images side by side, forcing them to stick to a height of 3cm. However, the following code achieves the side by side setting, but does not enforce the subfigures to be centered around the subcaptions.

```
\begin{figure}[caption={Some Picture A}, label={fig:a}]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[height=3cm]{figures/a-1.pdf}
  \caption{Picture A1}
  \label{fig:a-1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[height=3cm]{figures/a-2.pdf}
  \caption{Picture A2}
  \label{fig:a-2}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

This code results in the following:

[image]

However, it can be noticed that the sub-images themselves are not centered and in harmony with the centering enforced to the subcaptions. Any ideas for fixing these issues? Thank you!

Comment: the two subfigures add up  to `\textwidth` so the outer centering does nothing, apply `\centering`separately inside each subfigure to centre the`image within the subfigure

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two subfigures add up to `\textwidth` so the outer centering does nothing, apply `\centering` separately inside each `subfigure` to centre the image within the subfigure.